# 1st stimulus check

Tags: united-states, taxes, dependents, covid-19, stimulus

I was wrongfully claimed as a dependent in 2018. In 2019, I filed my taxes as head of household on 4/7/20. I received my refund exactly 8 days later and according to the IRS website my 2019 tax return was processed. Am I even eligible for the stimulus check? If so, why isn't the get my payment tool working for me and why haven't I received anything at all?

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb, but have you tried typing your address into the get my payment tool in all caps?

Comment: "why isn't the get my payment tool working for me" -- what do you mean by not working? Is there an error message it gives you?